# jquery: on click for html button not executing

Tags: jquery, buttonclick

The function switchDiv does not get called when any of the button is called. I am pretty new to Javascript/Jquery. I am sure i am making a mistake. No able to catch it. Kindly help.. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#be-data").on("click", function() { switchDiv(1); });
            $("#red-data").on("click", function(){switchDiv(2);});
            $("#green-data").on("click", function(){switchDiv(3);});
            $("#blue-data").on("click", function(){switchDiv(4);});;
            });

            var switchDiv = function (mapNum) {
                alert("fun" + mapNum);
                switch(mapNum) {
                    case 1:
                        $("#be-data").show();
                        $("#red-data").hide();
                        $("#green-data").hide();
                        $("#blue-data").hide();
                    alert("case 1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $("#be-data").hide();
                        $("#red-data").show();
                        $("#green-data").hide();
                        $("blue-data").hide();
                    alert("case 2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $("#be-data").hide();
                        $("#red-data").hide();
                        $("#green-data").show();
                        $("blue-data").hide();
                    alert("case 3);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $("#be-data").hide();
                        $("#red-data").hide();
                        $("#green-data").hide();
                        $("blue-data").show();
                    alert("case 4");
                        break;
                    default:
                        $("#be-data").show();
                        $("#red-data").hide();
                        $("#green-data").hide();
                        $("#blue-data").hide();
                    alert("case def");
                    }
                }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
        <input type="button" id="be-data" value="be"/>
        <input type="button" id="red-data" value="red"/>
        <input type="button" id="green-data" value="green"/>
        <input type="button" id="blue-data" value="blue"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about making a proper small example? Not everyone would like to dig into 2 pages of random code.

Comment: Even if the example is big - provide a jsFiddle - while doing so you will find your error most of the times.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
alert("case 3);
```

with

```
alert("case 3");
```

a " is missing from the end.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing quotation mark on line 36

```
alert("case 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have written `alert("case 3);` you should write `alert("case 3");`.It will work then

Answer (score 0):

> It is not an answer you asked.It is suggestion the way to
>   go in jquery dynamically.you simplify the above code like this you
>   don't want any switch case and 5 or more on statements. the whole
>   functionality is covered by just 5 lines. Use the below code it much
>   faster than your code.

```
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {

        $(this).show();
        $("input[type='button']").not(this).hide();

 });
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/u2t6L/)